# varnish "Error 200 OK"

Tags: varnish

I am having trouble using varnish as backend to another varnish server. The front-end varnish uses Disk based caching and backend uses malloc which load-balances multiple backend servers. When I hit the backend server with www.example.com it retrieves pages perfectly, when I hit the front-end server I am receiving error: Error 200 OK

OK

#### Guru Meditation:

XID: 1692612819

---

Varnish cache server

. Is there any configuration changes to be made to use varnish caching server behind another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably due to the inconsistency between cache copies. Try applying HTTP/1.1 to access, and set the max-age for better synchronization.

> Cache-control: max-age: The HTTP/1.1 replacement for the Expires header. While Expires >specifies the validity period using a full time stamp (valid until X day at Y time), max-age >uses a relative system (valid for Z many seconds) to avoid potential problems with time zones >and unsynchronised clocks.

Reference: http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/CreatingHighPerformanceDynamicWebSitesWithTheVarnishHttpAccelerator

Comment: I have made changes to have headers with max-age in the backend and front-end. It did not make any difference. The response headers Connection-close, indicate something with keep-alive which on search point to HTTP1.0. But varnish by default uses version 1.1. Below are the response headers: Accept-Ranges:bytes age:10 Connection:close Content-Length:385 Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8 Date:Tue, 01 Jul 2014 03:49:48 GMT Retry-After:5 Server:Varnish Via:1.1 varnish X-Cache:MISS X-Varnish:1692811028